# UDF replace function - failing to recognize strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to replace names found in 'xml' fieldname as hyperlinks, by matching with the names in database_tags.

I have created a simple UDF, but it does not execute the query correctly, as it creates duplicate name tags within the XML fieldname.

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Tags](@XML VARCHAR(MAX))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
 AS
 BEGIN

  SELECT  @XML = REPLACE(@XML,[Name],'<a href="<a href="pagename.aspx?tag='+[name]+'">'+[name]+'</a>')
   FROM [dbo].[database_tags]
   where UploadDate >= '2014-09-01'

   RETURN @XML
   END
```

**UPDATE**:
I manage to update my function to the following below, however the function only is only recognizing one name from the XML fieldname data.

```
 DECLARE @N VARCHAR(MAX) 
 SELECT @N = [Name] FROM [dbo].[database_tags] 
 WHERE @XML LIKE '%'+[Name]+'%' 
 AND UploadDate >= '2014-09-01' 

 IF @N IS NOT NULL 
 BEGIN 
 SELECT  @XML = REPLACE(@XML, 
   @N, 
   '<a href="<a href="pagename.aspx?tag='+@N+'">'+@N+'</a>') 
 END 
 RETURN @XML 
 END
```

Please advice further if possible.  Many thanks

Comment: Any change if you use NVARCAHR insted of VARCHAR?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I just tried that, but it still outputs the same incorrect result, as shown above.  Please advice further, if possible.  Many thanks

Comment: I think this is a unicode(utf8) issue.Either use a `N'your input paramters here'` or change your column collation or something else.My unicode knowledge is shaky at best so this is just a hunch.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  `SELECT  @XML = REPLACE(@XML,[Name],N'<a href="<a href="pagename.aspx?tag='+[name]+'">'+[name]+'</a>')`, I tried your suggestion but i am sorry to inform, that it still outputs the same incorrect result.  thank you though.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for database_tags table and the expected output. It will be easier to investigate.

Comment: @dcp1986, Thank you for reply. I updated my post in regards to your request.  Please advice further, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor to loop through values in the table replace each name with the hyper link. But replace can force unwanted outcome. For example if a configured name is part of a separate string function will replace it with a hyperlink.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ReplaceTags](@XML VARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT name
FROM database_tags
Where UploadDate >= '2014-09-01'

OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 IF @Name IS NOT NULL 
 BEGIN 
 SELECT  @XML = REPLACE(@XML, 
   @Name, 
   '<a href="<a href="pagename.aspx?tag='+@Name+'">'+@Name+'</a>') 
 END 
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @Name
END

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;


 RETURN @XML 
 END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I appreciate your help and but the above the solution, throws a unexpected outcome on the my input data (XML).  I have updated my post above for further details.  Please advice further, if possible. Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you replace the original function with this one. I am getting the correct output for the given input. Please check this SQLFIDDLE (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d28cb/3).

Comment: Hi, Apology for the very late response.  I manage to get the above function work on my data model in sql server, by adding in a distinct clause to the select statement from database_tags. Thank you very much for your help and time.